# Create a bool list based on a list of float in python

Tags: python

This is a `sample_list  = [628.6, 628.25, 632.8, 634.65, 634.9, 635.85, 633.55]`

I want to create a bool list of true/false based on the condition that if a list value is greater than the previous value, it should be true, else false. In my case, result should be something like this:

```
mybools = [False,True,True,True,True,False]
```

how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
sample_list = [628.6, 628.25, 632.8, 634.65, 634.9, 635.85, 633.55]
bool_list = [bool(max(sample_list[i-1] - sample_list[i], 0)) 
             for i in range(1, len(sample_list))]
```

This uses the fact that floats can be cast to boolean values. Anyhint 0 is false, all else is True.

Comment: why not just `sample_list[i-1] < sample_list[i]`?

Comment: Actually that is much neater. Got too clever for my self. Upvote you

Comment: This approach also has potentially unexpected behavior with NaNs. `bool(max(sample_list[i-1] - sample_list[i], 0))` will be True whenever either entry is `NaN`, so you'll get Trues in the output list even though `sample_list[i-1] < sample_list[i]` is False.

Answer (score 0):

Using Numpy, you can accomplish this succinctly by first computing the first-order difference of the input list with [`numpy.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html#numpy.diff), and then inspecting the sign of each entry in the resulting array:

```
import numpy as np 

sample_list  = [628.6, 628.25, 632.8, 634.65, 634.9, 635.85, 633.55]

mybools = np.diff(sample_list) > 0

print(mybools.tolist())
```

outputs

```
[False, True, True, True, True, False]
```